# How to convert array to specific Json format

Tags: php, json

I have an array that i need to convert to json format

The array is the result of a array_count_values and it looks like this:

(The number of users can change)

```
array(4) {
  ["user1"]=>
  int(1)
  ["user2"]=>
  int(1)
  ["user3"]=>
  int(1)
  ["user4"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

and based on that array i need to build a JSON response that must follow this pattern:

```
$return = [
    ['username' => 'user1', 'accepted' => 1],
    ['username' => 'user2', 'accepted' => 1],
    ['username' => 'user3', 'accepted' => 1],
    ['username' => 'user4', 'accepted' => 3]
];
echo json_encode($return);
```

I've tried some "foreach" but i struggle a little with arrays and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You say you've tried with `foreach` you should be close, so share your code and we can maybe help with where you are going wrong.

Comment: Please share your code what you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a foreach loop to get the keys and values from your array to form the output:

```
$return = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $return[] = array('username' => $key, 'accepted' => $value);
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AvWfO)

Comment: This was exactly the code i needed! I was trying to do something like this but couldn't understand how i could "array push" to an associative array.

Comment: @ArturMendes sometimes you just need that fresh pair of eyes...

Comment: is it possible to do the same but for an extended version? like if you have $return[] = array('username' => USER, 'accepted' => VALUE, 'denied' => VALUE); but accepted and denied in separated arrays

Comment: @ArturMendes sure - if denied is also in an array indexed by the usernames (call it `$denials`), something like `$return[] = array('username' => $key, 'accepted' => $value, 'denied' => $denials[$key]);` should work